# How to use Scipy package for Interpolation of 3D data over time?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, nan, python-xarray

I have a 3D array with latitude, longitude and time as axis (245 timesteps). I want to interpolate missing data in several timesteps of the 3D array with data from the timestep before or after (because spatially will be difficults as there are blocks of missing data in my arrays) Here is how single timesteps look plotted:

[image] [image]

All I found are differnt functions from scipy package but they do not interpolate over time. Their 3D functions work with x,y,z arrays. But where can I include the timeaxis? Adding to that they also use point data (whereas I have rasterdata).

eg:
scipy.interpolate.interpn(points, values, xi, method='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=nan)

Do you have any ideas how I can fill this missing data?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Linear interpolation is linear interpolation - it doesn’t matter what the interpretation of your axes are. X, y, z, can mean anything, not just spatial dimensions. The only major consideration is whether you first want to fill nans In space with 2D interpolation such as with [`xr.DataArray.interpolate_na`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interpolate_na.html) and then extend the axis in time it do you want full 3D interpolation where you’re treating pixel distances in time and space equally?

Comment: Also - neither xarray nor scipy handle raster data and point data differently. So if you want to apply a special method for handling raster data you’ll need to be specific about exactly what you want to do

Comment: Thanks @Michaela Delgado for you fast reply. I dont want to fill the 2D with nan! I rather want that the linear interpolation treats the space interpolation (2D) and the interpolation equal. 
Did I understood it right, I can just use scipy.interpolate.interpn (with lat, lon and time) and it interpolates all nan data temporally and spacial the same? Or is there a way to predefine that first the spatial interpolation is done and then the temporal interpolation?

Comment: See the interpolate_na docs - this function interpolates valid data to fill NaNs - not the other way around. You need to decide which method you want to use, but yes either of these will work. If you want to use scipy’s 3d interpolation you’ll need to set up your array data to fit the format required by scipy, which takes an array of (points x dims) rather than a 3d array with nans inside.

Comment: Is there a way to use the interpolate_na function for lat and lon at the same time? I currently can only use it for one dimension.
Adding to that for the dimension time I get the error:                                             "dimension time on 0th function argument to apply_ufunc with dask='parallelized' consists of multiple chunks, but is also a core dimension. To fix, either rechunk into a single dask array chunk along this dimension, i.e., ``.chunk(dict(time=-1))``, or pass ``allow_rechunk=True`` in ``dask_gufunc_kwargs`` but beware that this may significantly increase memory usage."

Comment: oh yep you're right about interpolate_na - you'll probably want to use the scipy method. you can't interpolate in multiple dimensions across chunks - no way to get around that without writing something custom (and slow).

Comment: As interpolate_na  is not working I am back with scipy: 
# points = the regular grid of my array  
# values = the data on the regular grid of my array
# points_nan = the points that are evaluate as nan in my array
print(interpolate.interpn(points, values, points_nan)). Now I am back to my asked question which is not answered yet: my dims of the array are differing therefor I get the warning when interpolating: "The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending" --> what can I do about this? Are there other packages working better with 3D arrays than scipy? Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Nope - scipy is the right one. But please include your code if you want help. See the guide to [ask] and how to create a [mre]